# Can't locate PDL/Graphics/Simple.pm

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04, pdl

I'm new to using [`PDL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL) and after installing it under Ubuntu (12.04 LTS running on a Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8 as dual-boot with Windows 8.1)

I tried the first example given on [First Steps with PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps) but get an error message regarding [`PDL::Graphics::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Graphics::Simple) as shown below.  I'm guessing it might be something simple?

```
$ pdl
perlDL shell v1.357
...
Loaded PDL v2.007
Note: AutoLoader not enabled ('use PDL::AutoLoader' recommended)
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Simple
```

but get an error message:

```
Can't locate PDL/Graphics/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 70) line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
```

Answer (score 3):

[PDL::Graphics::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PDL-Graphics-Simple/README.pod) comes in a separate distribution from the main PDL library. Just install it with `cpan` or your OS package manager and you should be good to go.